# "On the one after," vs "on the one that followed."

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

Which one is more common, more idiomatic?

Example:

> My brother's exams would end next week, so we decided to take the trip on
>   the one after.
>
> My brother's exams would end next week, so we decided to take the trip on
>   the one that followed.

(I'm also open to better suggestions.)

Comment: Not related to the question, but instead of *ended* I'd prefer *would end/would have ended* or even *were ending/were to end*

Comment: To begin with, I am wondering why you use the past tense *ended* with *next week*. Should it not be *will end next week*? I think to be succinct you need to repeat the word *week*. Try *My brother's exams will end next week, so we decided to take the trip the week following*.  It is inelegant to use a word twice in the same sentence, but for clarity's sake here I think you need to.

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that. Updated the question.

Comment: @WS2 Or even more simply, just _end_. “My brother’s exams end next week, so we(’ve) decided to take the trip the week after that” is how I would naturally phrase it. (Whether to use _we decided_ or _we’ve decided_ depends on the bigger context of the conversation, but I doubt either would really sound very off in any context.)

Answer (score 2):

My brother's exams end next week, so we decided to take the trip the week after.

*Reasoning: You don't need to say "would end next week", it can be shortened to "end next week". As for the week after that, "the week after" is commonly used, for example, "week after next", which indicates two weeks from now (the week after next week), etc.*